electron/hole doping using VASP
I am using NELECT variable to add electron/ hole doping, after doping , it must reduce the band gap but for me electron doping reduce it however , hole doping increase it? Can you guide why this is happening ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In my INCAR file in VASP...I am using NELECT to add electron/hole...when there is no doping ...NELECT is 32 for SrTiO3, I reduced it to 31.5 to add hole doping, but after that it increased the band gap...based on other papers doping must reduce the gap!Global Parameters
NELECT = 31.5 ........................I am wondering what is wrong ? Also, I want to mention that after adding NELECT and relaxing the structure , I took CONTCAR file to use in second step in SCF and BAND structure calcultion and removed NELECT variable in their INCAR.

@Sam, could you please update your question with the details you mentioned in the comment? You can choose 'Edit' and then modify your question accordingly.
